# Unique Identifier Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

Following is a table of asp membership provider.I am trying to add multiple user of same application but I am unable to add duplicate values in `ApplicationId` column. Why is this so?

Here is my query which I am using to insert records in table:

```
Insert into Users 
values ('97C84F32-26A6-4A6C-960E-89A6A14D54E4', 'C2CADEDE-DA70-4C25-B717-6970344C8B34', 'John_doe', '', '', 1, '2014-11-05 21:28:33.043')

Insert into Users 
values ('97C84F32-26A6-4A6C-960E-89A6A14D54E4', 'D2CADEDE-CA70-4C25-B717-6970344C8B34', 'John_doe1', '', '', 1, '2014-11-05 21:28:33.043')
```

Error

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Users' with unique index 'aspnet_Users_Index'. The duplicate key value is (97c84f32-26a6-4a6c-960e-89a6a14d54e4, ).

Here is my user table query :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users]
(
    [ApplicationId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [LoweredUserName] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [MobileAlias] [nvarchar](16) NULL,
    [IsAnonymous] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [LastActivityDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC)
        WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
              ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Users] ADD  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [UserId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Users] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [MobileAlias]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Users] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsAnonymous]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Users] WITH CHECK 
    ADD FOREIGN KEY([ApplicationId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Applications] ([ApplicationId])
GO
```

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Show us the SQL you're using to add those users!

Comment: I suspect you either can't add duplicated values in `UserId` or the `ApplicationId` value doesn't exist in `Applications`?

Comment: @marc_s I Have added that in my question

Comment: What error do you get when running that SQL?

Comment: OK - thanks - but that's just one row - you talked about inserting **multiple** rows of data. Please show us a **second** row that you're inserting with the same `ApplicationId` that fails .....

Comment: @DavidG It does exsist in applications .I can add the record for the first time but when I use same applicationId for the second row it says "Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Users' with unique index 'aspnet_Users_Index'. The duplicate key value is (97c84f32-26a6-4a6c-960e-89a6a14d54e4, )."

Comment: OK, so you can't insert the same `UserId`, not `ApplicationId`

Comment: And `UserId` is a primary key constraint, as defined by your table definition.  So...  there's your problem.

Comment: @Siyual I am trying to add same ApplicationId not the UserID

Comment: @DavidG Exactly that's my point I can't insert same userId but I can isert same applicationId.It wont let me add applicationId as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you have a `PRIMARY KEY` on your table on the `UserId` column. This means you are unable to insert multiple rows with the same value in that column.

If you want to insert the same `UserId` but with different `ApplicationId`, you should change your primary key to be a composite key including both `UserId` and `ApplicationId`.

Alternatively, it may be that your `INSERT` statement needs changing as you are relying on column position being correct. Instead specify the columns:

```
Insert into Users
(ApplicationId, UserId, UserName, LoweredUserName, MobileAlias, IsAnonymous, LastActivityDate)
values
('97C84F32-26A6-4A6C-960E-89A6A14D54E4','C2CADEDE-DA70-4C25-B717-6970344C8B34','John_doe','','',1,'2014-11-05 21:28:33.043')

Insert into Users
(ApplicationId, UserId, UserName, LoweredUserName, MobileAlias, IsAnonymous, LastActivityDate)
values
('97C84F32-26A6-4A6C-960E-89A6A14D54E4','D2CADEDE-CA70-4C25-B717-6970344C8B34','John_doe1','','',1,'2014-11-05 21:28:33.043')
```

**UPDATE**

With a bit of research, the `aspnet_Users` table by default has a UNIQUE index on `UserId` and `LoweredUserName`. Just specify a unique LoweredUserName value:

```
Insert into Users
(ApplicationId, UserId, UserName, LoweredUserName, MobileAlias, IsAnonymous, LastActivityDate)
values
('97C84F32-26A6-4A6C-960E-89A6A14D54E4','C2CADEDE-DA70-4C25-B717-6970344C8B34','John_doe','john doe','',1,'2014-11-05 21:28:33.043')

Insert into Users
(ApplicationId, UserId, UserName, LoweredUserName, MobileAlias, IsAnonymous, LastActivityDate)
values
('97C84F32-26A6-4A6C-960E-89A6A14D54E4','D2CADEDE-CA70-4C25-B717-6970344C8B34','John_doe1','john_doe1','',1,'2014-11-05 21:28:33.043')
```

Comment: I want to insert same applicationId with different UserId's

Comment: No it's still not letting me add same values in ApplicationId Column

Comment: Then you have another index on your table that you are not showing us. In fact, the index is called `aspnet_Users_Index`.